# How to send a value from PHP to NodeJS, then back to PHP?

Tags: php, node.js, send, getvalue

All I want to do is to send a value from PHP to NodeJS for processing.
Then when NodeJS finished processing the value, send the value back to PHP.

**Desired PHP:**

```
<?php
   $value = 'someVal';
   $url = 'http://123.456.789:8080/processing/'

   $newValue = mysteriousFunctionThatSendsTheDataToNodeJSThatIDontKnowAbout($url, $value);
?>
```

**Desired NodeJS:**

```
router.post('/processing/', function(request, response){ 
   var value = request.body.value;

   //VALUE BEING PROCESSED

   response.send(value);
});
```

Some notes: Doesn't matter if it it is router.post or router.get or router.whatever, I just need the value go from PHP to NodeJS then back to PHP.

Comment: Don't you just need to do a network request to the nodejs server?

Comment: @AdamForbis I am not sure what you mean by that. I need to send from PHP to NodeJS, rather than request from NodeJS end. The value originates from PHP and I cannot "get" it from NodeJS end first.

Comment: you could use curl to send out an http request with parameters, and let node respond as json to the http request. Php side, decode the json response with the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to  make ***ajax call*** and send your data to  ***nodejs*** route. In nodejs insatll ***body parser***. After when you will get JSON in server side , make what you want and via ***res.send(JSON.stringlifly())*** command send it to browser and in client side take returned data via **ajax callback**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) for that (or whatever who can make a HTTP request).